# default-display-manager error

Tags: gdm

I was using gnome desktop manager, then I changed the file

```
./etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

to nothing, so the login would be made via command line.
The problem is that there's a file created in the same folder with the name

```
default-display-manager~
```

But when I boot the pc gdm starts to load and never finishes.
I tried to acess the shell via recovery mode but I'm not able to modify files.

Please assist, I'm in chaos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modify the `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file in recovery mode after re-mounting the root filesystem with read-write permissions

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

The `default-display-manager~` file is likely just a backup automatically created by the editor that you used - it probably has nothing to do with your situation. You can delete it when you're done.

I'm not familiar with using an empty `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file as a way to suppress GUI startup. If GDM is started via `upstart` you may want to look at using an `/etc/init/gdm.override` file (containing the single entry `manual`) instead.

Comment: I tested on a Virtual Machine booting ubuntu with default-display-manager empty and it booted perfectly via command line. But in that case I'm using ubuntu minimal install w/o gnome wm and fluxbox.